# jQuery animation glitches out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to make a cool animation with jQuery, but my skills with jQuery isn't that great so I have to ask about my problem here since I can't figure out the problem myself. What Im trying to do is to make a order plan, but it's acting weird.

Here's a gif of my problem: https://gyazo.com/0ebae3cc3eff811ea3ec411a638343cd

As you can see, if I select a "plan" after I've selected one from before, it glitches out and doesn't make sense. Here's my jerky JS/JQ code:

```
<script>
  $('.services').on('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('dataid');
    $("#"+target).toggle('fast').siblings(".selected").hide();
  });

  $('.service').click(function(event) {
    $('.service').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });

  $('.package').click(function(event) {
    $('.package').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
</script>
```

A friend of mine suggested this fix: http://pastebin.com/YHxtpC1z.
But it doesn't work either, and makes the page look even more glitched.

Im not that good with JavaScript nor jQuery, but I am happy to learn! So please tell me what Im doing wrong, and correct me! I tried to keep the information minimal, but complete. So if I missed something, please tell me, so I can add it in.

Thanks.

Comment: Could please explain what _"glitches out"_ means? Its not very descriptive

Comment: Make a jsfiddle so we can experiment, or post html structure

Comment: @ProEvilz It's way to much stuff to make it into a JSFiddle. Too many files/lines, as Im not sure what is what.

Comment: @zgood The GIF in the posts shows exactly what the problem is. If I select window1, it shows up as normal. But if I select window2 while window1 is toggled it toggles the whole thing off again. Visually the window is toggled, but the "step 2" part is gone. Hard to explain.

Comment: @m0nsterr hmmm ok I think I have a better understanding now